# Ввод и вывод строк TASM/Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, dos, tasm

Ввожу строку, нажимаю Enter, но при выводе строки (после прерывания) выводится мусор.

[image: Вывод строки]

```
STACKSG SEGMENT PARA STACK
    DW 128 DUP(?)
STACKSG ENDS
;---------------------
DATASG SEGMENT PARA
    BUFF LABEL BYTE
    MAX_LEN = 128
    MaxSymb DB MAX_LEN
    LEN DB ?
    STRING DB MAX_LEN DUP(?)
DATASG ENDS
;---------------------
CODESG SEGMENT PARA
    ASSUME DS:DATASG, CS:CODESG, ES:CODESG, SS:STACKSG
START:
    .386
    PUSH DS
    MOV AX, DATASG
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    XOR AX, AX
    ;--------------------
    LEA DX, BUFF
    MOV AH, 10
    INT 21H



    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H


    ;завершение программы
    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h
CODESG ENDS
END START
```

Comment: А заменять энтер на доллар Пушкин будет?

Comment: @Akina, попробую сейчас

Comment: @Akina, я же правильно понимаю, что эта строка сохранится в переменную string, или все-таки она сохранится в DX?

Comment: @HideME, регистр DX - 2 байта. Строка - много байт. Физически нельзя уместить всю строку в двухбайтовый регистр (если она длиннее 2 байт, конечно же). В DX у вас записывается смещение ("адрес", точнее часть физического адреса) метки BUFF. Введенный текст попадает в область памяти начиная с метки STRING. Вот здесь описано как работает `int 21h ah=0Ah`: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/dos_0018.php

Answer (score 0):

```
STACKSG SEGMENT PARA STACK
    DW 128 DUP(?)
STACKSG ENDS
;---------------------
DATASG SEGMENT PARA
    MAX_LEN = 128
    STRING DB MAX_LEN, MAX_LEN DUP('$')
DATASG ENDS
;---------------------
CODESG SEGMENT PARA
    ASSUME DS:DATASG, CS:CODESG, ES:CODESG, SS:STACKSG
START:
    .386
    PUSH DS
    MOV AX, DATASG
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX
    XOR AX, AX
    ;--------------------
    LEA DX, STRING
    MOV AH, 10
    INT 21H

    ;вывод на экран
    MOV STRING+1, 0AH
    LEA DX, STRING+1
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H


    ;завершение программы
    MOV AX, 4C00h
    INT 21h
CODESG ENDS
END START
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант кода на диалекте fasm (основное отличие от диалекта tasm в данном случае - для tasm смещения нужно указывать с ключевым словом `offset`: `mov dx, offset buff` и `mov dx, offset string`), компилируется в com:

```
org 100h

; Считываем строку
mov dx, buff
mov ah, 0Ah
int 21h

; Выводим перенос строки
mov dl, 0Ah
mov ah, 2
int 21h

; Выводим строку
mov dx, string
mov ah, 9
int 21h

mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h

buff:
    max_len = 128
    MaxSymb db max_len
    len db ?
    string db max_len+1 dup ('$')
```

[image: Скриншот]